# cross platform (mac/win) way to write uboot to specific location on sd card

Tags: c++, windows, macos, u-boot, userspace

I am working on a cross platform (mac / windows) updater tool to write an uboot SPL to a specific location on an SD card.

I basically want to do the equivalent of this linux command, from my user space C++ application:

```
sudo dd if=out of=/dev/sdb seek=64 conv=notrunc
```

where "out" is a concatenation of the uboot SPL and dtb.

**Questions:**

1. is there a way to do this from user space on Mac OSX and Windows?
2. is there an open source cross platform library that can write binary files to specific locations on disk (sd card) without requiring kernel drivers?

**I've googled around but could not find any toolkits or libraries that do this.**

Comment: open, write, close.  All pretty standard.

Comment: @stark it's not as simple as that :-)